# Android PreferenceActivity code to access Phonebook contact

Tags: android, android-manifest

I want to access Phonebook contact from my `PreferenceActivity` having some `EditText`, so that when clicking `EditText` it will redirect to contact screen to choose contact. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code in click or touch event of Edittext

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
if (intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
}
```

and then add

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT) {
        if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
            contactPicked(data);
        }
    }
}

private void contactPicked(Intent data) {
    ContentResolver cr = activity.getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    cur.moveToFirst();
    try {
        // getData() method will have the Content Uri of the selected contact
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        //Query the content uri
        cur = activity.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        // column index of the contact ID
        String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        // column index of the contact name
        String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        // column index of the phone number
        Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{id}, null);
        while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
            String phone = pCur.getString(
                    pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)).replaceAll(" ", "");

            //Here you can set phone number
            etMobile.setText(phone);

            //Toast.show(phone);
        }
        pCur.close();
        // column index of the email
        Cursor emailCur = cr.query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{id}, null);
        while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {
            // This would allow you get several email addresses
            // if the email addresses were stored in an array
            String email = emailCur.getString(
                    emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS));
        }
        emailCur.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: where to put the code for onClick event? In PreferenceScreen usiing intent?

Comment: on the click or touch or drawable click event of the edittext you have in preference screen.

Comment: Thank You it works. Again I want to get the value of contact from contact list and save it .But while accessing contact the app is crashing.Any suggestion??

Comment: without logcat, very difficult to find the issue.

Comment: I will try to fix it. Can you please go through my one question i posted in stack overflow ? It will be very helpful if you try to solve the issue.Here is the link.                                                                             [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39398127/6810431)